# HP Desktop stuck on StartUp repair after time freeze

Tags: windows-7

Im a student working on a computer lab for our robotics team, and after our initial setup, which consisted of reinstalling the operating system to Windows 7, we attempted to put Toolwiz Time Freeze on our computers to stop students from editing the computers. Unfortunately, our first test computer is locked on startup repair after the installation. How can we access the harddrive contents / boot up or will we have to reimage the computer?

Answer (score 0):

From your query i believe that you have reinstalled the OS and now not able to login in the machine.

If you wanted to access the data available in the machine then you can attach the drive in another machine as secondary drive by setting disk preference in bios. You can access the data with out any issues.

If you wanted to fix the booting issue. Then check whether any blue screen error is showing before going in to repair mode. Errors like 7B,7E and google the error and try fixing it.

(or)

While booting click F8 and try booting with safe mode or use "restore to last known good configuration option".